# How to elegantly one hot encode a series of lists in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

So I have the following data:

```
>>> test = pd.Series([['a', 'b', 'e'], ['c', 'a'], ['d'], ['d'], ['e']])
>>> test

0    [a, b, e]
1       [c, a]
2          [d]
3          [d]
4          [e]
```

I am trying to one-hot-encode all of the data in the lists back into my dataframe. To look like this:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]],
             columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   1   0   0   1
1   1   0   1   0   0
2   0   0   0   1   0
3   0   0   0   1   0
4   0   0   0   0   1
```

I have tried researching and I've found similar problems but none like this. I have attempted:

```
test.apply(pd.Series)
```

But that doesn't quite accomplish the one-hot aspect. That simply unpacks my lists in an arbitrary order. I'm sure I could figure out a lengthly solution but I'd be glad to hear if there's a more elegant way to perform this.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I am aware that I can iterate through my `test` series, then create a column for each unique value found, then go back and iterate through `test` again, flagging said columns for unique values. But that doesn't seem very pandorable to me and I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Scikit is about to get an upgraded onehotencoder that will encode strings, FWIW: https://medium.com/dunder-data/from-pandas-to-scikit-learn-a-new-exciting-workflow-e88e2271ef62

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`MultiLabelBinarizer` from the `sklearn` library is more efficient for these problems. It should be preferred to `apply` with `pd.Series`. Here's a demo:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

test = pd.Series([['a', 'b', 'e'], ['c', 'a'], ['d'], ['d'], ['e']])

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

res = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(test),
                   columns=mlb.classes_,
                   index=test.index)
```

**Result**

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  0  0  1
1  1  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  0  1  0
3  0  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: If in the pandas `pd.DataFrame(test.values.tolist()).stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
`

Comment: @Wen, Yep, good one. Shameful to say but I've never conceptually appreciated `stack`, hence very rarely use it. Also seems to be the weak link in efficiency.

Comment: then just do not use it :-) `pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(test.values.tolist()),prefix_sep ='',prefix='').sum(level=0, axis = 1)
`

Comment: I didn't know about this tool and I guess I didn't word my google searches well enough to find it. This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Just a heads up: Using MultiLabelBinarizer is several times faster than the `stack().str.get_dummies.sum()` approach.